# How do I implement an 'order' property with AJAX data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I am making an asynchronous 'GET' request using the Parse API. The AJAX request returns an array of strings that may not be in the right order. I have searched on Google for an 'order' property AJAX may possess but no luck.

This is my AJAX request as a function called retrieve getting the value of the text property.

**AJAX Request:**

```
Obj.retrieve = function(callBack) {
   $.ajax({
       url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/messages',
       type : 'GET',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       contentType : 'application/json',
       data : JSON.stringify({   
           text : 'value: ',
           order: "-createdAt"          // Would the order property go here?        
       }),
       error : function(data) {
           console.log('error: ' + data);
       },
       success : function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data["results"].length; i++)
             callBack(data["results"][i].text);
       }
   });
};
```

**TL;DR**:  Each object has field names createdAt, updatedAt, and objectId thanks to Parse. Ideally, I would like to use createdAt with the order. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Sort it on the server side
2. Sort it manually:

   ```
   data['results'].sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? -1 : 1;
   });
   ```

Comment: I don't have access to the server side. I am only able to make an AJAX request within <script> on the HTML doc. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @andystructible: so see the item #2 ;-)

Comment: WOW I see what you did there. Would #2 belong in the data or success property of the AJAX request?

Comment: @andystructible: the code at #2 doesn't care of where you got the data from, it's just a generic way to sort an arbitrary array. So you just need to run it right after you've received an array and before you need it to be sorted.

Comment: that's awesome. I will give it a try and be in touch.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` argument in your `$.ajax` request gets sent to the server; so you would use that on the server to sort your results.

If you're not sorting on the server, you need to sort in your `success:` callback.  Suggest you use something like this:

```
Obj.retrieve = function(sortBy, callBack) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/messages',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify({   
            text : 'value: ' // maybe not needed?
        }),
        error : function(data) {
            console.log('error: ' + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data['results'].sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.sortBy - b.sortBy;
            });
            $.each(data['results'], function (n, v) {
                callBack(v.text);
            });
        });
};
```

Warning: This was compiled in my head.

Your usage would be something like `o.retrieve('createdAt', function () { });`, or `o.retrieve('updatedAt', function () { });`, or `o.retrieve('objectId', function () { });`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the order method as your data type and use -.

```
 Obj.retrieve = function(callBack) {
   $.ajax({
       url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/messages',
       type : 'GET',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       contentType : 'application/json',
       data : 'order=-createdAt', //REQUEST FROM NEWEST
       }),
       error : function(data) {
           console.log('error: ' + data);
       },
       success : function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data["results"].length; i++)
             callBack(data["results"][i].text);
       }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ we read:

- Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL.

So for this, we should be able to rework the request URL to be:
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=createdAt